# C# Passing Type as a variable. How to accomplish?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have some code that I want to be able to reuse. To do this I need to pass the DbSet type in dynamically. How would I get this to work?

```
 public virtual DbSet<Runlist> Runlists { get; set; }
```

```
public void Method(Type myType)
{
    using (var ctx = new FpContext())
    {
        Type myVariableType = myType;
        var table = "myTable";

        var sql = ctx.Database
            .SqlQuery<myVariableType>("SELECT * FROM  @table WHERE (UserId = @userid)"
            , new SqlParameter("@userid", user.Id)
            , new SqlParameter("@table", table)).ToList();
    }

foreach (var r in sql)
{
    foreach (XElement e in xmlDoc.Descendants(ns + "RateRequest"))
    {
        var originCode = e.Element(ns + "RequestedShipment").Element(ns + "Shipper").Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "PostalCode");
        var postalCode = e.Element(ns + "RequestedShipment").Element(ns + "Recipient").Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "PostalCode");
        var shipTime = e.Element(ns + "RequestedShipment").Element(ns + "ShipTimestamp");
        var serviceType = e.Element(ns + "RequestedShipment").Element(ns + "ServiceType");
        var totalWeight = e.Element(ns + "RequestedShipment").Element(ns + "TotalWeight").Element(ns + "Value");
        var packageCount = e.Element(ns + "RequestedShipment").Element(ns + "PackageCount");
        var weight = e.Element(ns + "RequestedShipment").Element(ns + "RequestedPackageLineItems").Element(ns + "Weight").Element(ns + "Value");

        originCode.SetValue(origin);
        postalCode.SetValue(r.Zipcode);
        shipTime.SetValue(dt);
        serviceType.SetValue("FEDEX_GROUND");
        totalWeight.SetValue(r.TotalWeight);
        packageCount.SetValue(r.BoxCount);
        weight.SetValue(r.Weight);
    }

    xmlDoc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Requests/SoapRequest_v24.xml"));

}
}
```

I have posted additional code to try and explain more to what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: You can use reflection, but generally speaking generics don't work with runtime types

Comment: See the [documentation of SqlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0), use the proper overload.

Comment: On the comments below you say: "Any suggestions on how to implement this and access the column names of the Dbset?" 

Do you want a generic query builder where you can write something like: `RunList.Get(x => x.Name, x.Time, x.Location).ToList<T2>();` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SqlQuery method from EntityFramework there is an overload that receives the type as parameter, so your code could be something like:

```
public void Method(Type myType)
{
    using (var ctx = new FpContext())
    {
        Type myVariableType = myType;
        var table = "myTable";

        var sql = ctx.Database
            .SqlQuery(myVariableType, "SELECT * FROM  @table WHERE (UserId = @userid)"
            , new SqlParameter("@userid", user.Id)
            , new SqlParameter("@table", table)).ToList();
    }
}
```

You can check that method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_Database_SqlQuery_System_Type_System_String_System_Object___).

Comment: I tried this suggestion but I loose the ToList method and can't access the table columns any longer.

Comment: Can you share mode details about what do you wanna do with the output list?